# How do I host my Django app on the intranet?

Tags: python, django, unix, web-applications, deployment

I have successfully developed a Django app. The requirement is to deploy the app over an on-premise server. The application is accessible on the intranet using the development environment. Is any web server is preferred to deploy this application locally (or) should I leave the terminal running the server as it is so that the users can access the application as they are already doing it? I am using a unix server.

Comment: Are you using ssh to login to the server? What IP are you using? Have you put the IP in the ALLOWED_HOSTS? You can use 'screen' to keep the terminal on the server running so it stays alive even after you kill your terminal.

Comment: I recommend using Nginx with Gunicorn or uwsgi to host your application.

Comment: While you could leave the command line running but it is not advised to do. Django docs recommends against it.

Comment: Generally it's all the same as on the internet. Setup server (Apache, Nginx, whatever) and run it as in production.

Comment: @pissall

I have direct login access to it. 
I am using the static IP assigned to it.
Yes it is allowed

Comment: @sebb I guess this should be fine.

Comment: This will be fine, we are using gunicorn and uwsgi on many production releases. They are super easy to setup. Also I recommend setting up a supervisor to restart your application in case it fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the question is actually on deployment model, I suggest to take a look at [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/) on deployment. Depending on load, uWSGI/Gunicorn [+ nginx] will be good choice.

Independent of tools you use, no need to leave running terminal on your server. There's a lot of tools to "daemonize" processes. Simplest would be [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/)